# Sum a Distinct Count with datepart(day)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, distinct

Here is my issue.  This is a tanning salon and we have recently added spa services. Clients use to tan just time in a day so counting distinct clients by employee was pretty easy. Now They tan/spa more then one time in a day and see different staff on any given day.  I am trying to SUM the dinstinct client count by day into one number.  Here is the query.  I hope this make sense. Please forgive me as first time I have posted?

This query will produce the count of distinct client each day they come in and which employee tanned them. (Which is correct) I just need to sum this by employee. If I do not include the date part it selects distinct for the entire date range.

```
SELECT   COUNT(DISTINCT ClientUID) AS [# clients], DATEPART(day, DateOfTan) AS [day of tan], EmployeeUID
FROM     History_TanHistory
WHERE    DateOfTan > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-06-01 00:00:00', 102) 
     AND DateOfTan < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-07-01 00:00:00', 102)
     AND Deleted = 0 AND Borrow = 0 AND AddedBack = 0 AND CanceledTan = 0
GROUP BY EmployeeUID, DATEPART(day, DateOfTan)
```

The above query produces this type of output (without the sum at bottom)
EmployeeUID         day of tan      # clients
383-E11132012143712J1U  1   52
383-E11132012143712J1U  2   80
383-E11132012143712J1U  3   68
383-E11132012143712J1U  5   58
383-E11132012143712J1U  6   78
383-E11132012143712J1U  7   65
383-E11132012143712J1U  9   85
383-E11132012143712J1U  10  64
383-E11132012143712J1U  11  65
383-E11132012143712J1U  13  55
383-E11132012143712J1U  14  55
383-E11132012143712J1U  16  76
383-E11132012143712J1U  17  65
383-E11132012143712J1U  18  50
383-E11132012143712J1U  20  55
383-E11132012143712J1U  21  56
383-E11132012143712J1U  23  47
383-E11132012143712J1U  24  79
383-E11132012143712J1U  25  59
383-E11132012143712J1U  27  55
383-E11132012143712J1U  28  54
383-E11132012143712J1U  30  62

total       1383

If the datepart is removed it looks at the entire 30 day period as one grouping and only returns distinct count of 656 for this employee.

I need it to return the sum of 1383.

sample data for above employee.   the client id may use services more then 1 time in a davy but I only want to count one time.

Comment: Some sample input and desired output would be helpful here.

Comment: Your requirement is not very clear, `group by` itself makes pairs of id and datepart distinct, so `count` should work expectedly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, just wrap your query as a sub-query.

This will return one row with one total number.

```
SELECT
    SUM(T.[# clients]) AS TotalClients
FROM
(
    SELECT   COUNT(DISTINCT ClientUID) AS [# clients], DATEPART(day, DateOfTan) AS [day of tan], EmployeeUID
    FROM     History_TanHistory
    WHERE    DateOfTan > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-06-01 00:00:00', 102) 
         AND DateOfTan < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-07-01 00:00:00', 102)
         AND Deleted = 0 AND Borrow = 0 AND AddedBack = 0 AND CanceledTan = 0
    GROUP BY EmployeeUID, DATEPART(day, DateOfTan)
) AS T
```

If you want a `SUM` per employee, just add another `GROUP BY`. This will return one row per `EmployeeUID`:

```
SELECT
    T.EmployeeUID
    ,SUM(T.[# clients]) AS ClientsPerEmployee
FROM
(
    SELECT   COUNT(DISTINCT ClientUID) AS [# clients], DATEPART(day, DateOfTan) AS [day of tan], EmployeeUID
    FROM     History_TanHistory
    WHERE    DateOfTan > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-06-01 00:00:00', 102) 
         AND DateOfTan < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-07-01 00:00:00', 102)
         AND Deleted = 0 AND Borrow = 0 AND AddedBack = 0 AND CanceledTan = 0
    GROUP BY EmployeeUID, DATEPART(day, DateOfTan)
) AS T
GROUP BY T.EmployeeUID
```

Comment: That solved the problem.  that was to easy I don't why I did not think of that.  Thank you Vladimir.

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped you, consider upvoting and accepting it.